# How to set iframe video on my slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/59/

This is script for slider:

```
$(function() {
        $('#slides').crossSlide({
            speed: 40,
            fade: 1
        }, [
            { src: 'img/photo-2.jpg', dir: 'up', alt: 'Our Business is to Encrypt and Secure Your Communications', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-10.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'The Solution for Secured Communications and Privacy.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-3.jpg', dir: 'up', alt: 'All Text and Phone Communications are Encrypted End-to-End.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-4.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'Secured Communications for Law Enforcement and Public Officials.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-5.jpg', dir: 'up', alt: 'Secured Communications for the U.S. Military.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-6.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'The World Leader in Encrypted Communications.', href: '#'  },
            { src: 'img/photo-7.jpg', dir: 'down', alt: 'The Solution for Corporate Executives, Law Enforcement, Homeland Security, Goverment Agencies and more...', href: '#'  }

        /*  */
        ], function(idx, img, idxOut, imgOut) {
            if (idxOut == undefined) {
                if(idx == 0 || idx == 3 || idx == 6 || idx == 9){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-425px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-480px';
                }else if(idx == 1 || idx == 4 || idx == 7 || idx == 10 || idx == 12){
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-425px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-480px';
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginTop = '-425px';
                    document.getElementById('crossSlideCaption').style.marginLeft = '-480px';
                };
                $('div.caption').text(img.alt).animate({ opacity: 1.0 })
            } else {
                //$('div.caption').animate({ opacity: 0 })
            }});
            $('div.caption').show().css({ opacity: 0 })
        });
```

Now everything working fine, Now i need to add iframe video to my slideshow like as caption.

My video size 420x234 pixels, Here is the code for iframe video:

```
<iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/bqur1fvyag?videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="720" height="433"></iframe>
<script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
```

But i am blank how can i add in my existing code.

Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to append this iframe to your `'#crossSlideCaption'`? then simply change `$('div.caption').text(img.alt)` to `$('div.caption').html(img.alt)`and paste your code in the `alt` attribute, but I fell It's kinda strange request…

Comment: I need caption as well as iframe video @Kaiido .. thanks

Comment: @Kaiido: already i have caption in alt attribute right? so how can i add <iframe> code in alt attribute?

Comment: So you need iframe to be append like other images in slider or do you need it to be in caption of one of the images  ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j88u02o2/66/) for the second hypothesis)

Comment: Yes, i need caption in right side, as well as i need also iframe in left side... I need both for all image silder.. thanks

Comment: i can able to set either caption or iframe.. so may i know. how to set both? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
<script>
  wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("bqur1fvyag", {
    videoFoam: {
    maxWidth: 420,
    maxHeight: 234
     },
    plugin: {
      "socialbar-v1": {
        buttons: ""
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```